# How can I get my browser's POST request' string?

Tags: post, browser, httprequest

How can I get the string of my browser's POST requests?

Is there any browser extension for this?

Comment: Don't you think it would make a lot of sense to mention what browser you are using?

Comment: @xbonez doesn't matter, FireFox, Chrome or IE

Comment: It does if you're asking for browser extensions. FF has Live HTTP Headers (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/), Chrome has HTTP Headers (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/http-headers/hplfkkmefamockhligfdcfgfnbcdddbg). The advantage of browser extensions are that they allow you to change the headers before shooting off the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Fiddler2: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/. That runs along side of your browsers, not as a plugin. So it will work with all of your browsers at the same time. It will allow you to capture requests originating on your machine and inspect the POST data, responses, and you can insert breakpoints for additional debugging.